# I can't evaluate links in laravel 4 pagination

Tags: php, laravel-4, pagination

I have 2 tables: posts and comments. Post and Comment has one-to-many relationship.

I have managed to evaluate paginations of posts and comments with following code:

```
$posts = Post::with(array(
          'comments' => function($c) {
                            $c->paginate(5);
                        }))
          ->paginate(10);
```

First line below gives the links of $posts, but the second doesn't.

```
{{ $posts->links() }}
{{ $post->comments->links() }}
```

It gives the following error:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links()
```

How can I evaluate the links of comments of each post?

Note: {{ $post->comments }} gives the comments of the specified post.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
{{ $posts->comments->link }}
```

if it's not working, try:

```
{{ $posts->comments()->link }}
```

Make sure you've set up the relationship correctly first.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
{{ $post->comments()->links() }}
```

Comment: That doesn't work: It gives following error: ErrorException
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::links()

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two things to figure out here:

1. If you have posts paginated AND comments paginated, how do you go forward and back on posts and comments on the same web page? (Do you want to just limit the number of comments?
2. I don't think Laravel will paginate on relationships like that (as evidenced by that not working).

I think we need to know what you want to have as a result of this query. In what scenario are you paginating both posts and its child comments at the same time?

Comment: I just wanted to go forward and back on both posts and comments (e.g. Suppose that posts has 2 pages, and each post has 3 pages of comments. If I click the page 3 of the comments of the first post, I expect to go page 1 of posts (which is the current page) and page 3 of the comments of the first post. I think it is a reasonable demand, isn't it?

Comment: If this isn't possible, how can I implement a nested structure like the ones we see in fb or others? How would you implement that?

Comment: In fact, it is also OK a "More" button at the end of a limited number of comments of each post, and whenever "More" button pressed I want to add one page of comments. But I don't know how to do.